# Need to turn this php into WP shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I need to turn this code:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'echo_ald_crp' ) ) echo_ald_crp(); ?>
```

into a shortcode. Can someone help me do this? I have researched but am just lost to be honest. 
Thanks!

Comment: what is "echo_ald_crp()" does?

Comment: It's a plugin that displays related blog posts based off of the page title.

Comment: If you're adding this to the end of every single posts content, you would be better off adding it to your theme template instead of as a shortcode

Answer (score 3):

Init your shortcode

```
add_shortcode('shortcode_ald_crp', 'myshortcode_echo_ald_crp');
```

The function what you want:

```
function myshortcode_echo_ald_crp() {
    ob_start(); 
    if ( function_exists( 'echo_ald_crp' ) ) echo_ald_crp();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

you call you shortcode in a post like this:

```
[shortcode_ald_crp]
```

Or into the php code:

```
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_ald_crp]');
```

**UPDATE**

Change the function `add_shortcode`

`shortcode_ald_crp` for `myshortcode_echo_ald_crp`

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the shortcode [shortcode_ald_crp] but it just displays that text rather than the blog posts. I added everything you said to the functions. What would cause that? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure `that echo_ald_crp()` return the whole blog post? Because it is suppose to alter the "output".

Comment: Yes. I am currently using the PHP script on my product page template, and it's showing the related blog posts.

Comment: I added this to my functions: `//blog posts

add_shortcode('shortcode_ald_crp', 'myshortcode_echo_ald_crp');

function shortcode_ald_crp() {
    ob_start(); 
    if ( function_exists( 'echo_ald_crp' ) ) echo_ald_crp();
    return ob_get_clean();
}`

Comment: So all you see is `[shortcode_ald_crp]` ? And this code is in functions.php of your active theme?

Comment: Yes exactly. [link]http://imgur.com/OChshoW

Comment: I update the answer.. make a mistake

Comment: If the answer is Correct, please [Accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this (untested):

```
// function for your shortcode
function shortcode_action($atts) {

        ob_start();
        if ( function_exists( 'echo_ald_crp' ) ) echo_ald_crp();
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
}

// creates shortcode [shortcodehandle] so change it accordingly
add_shortcode( 'shortcodehandle', 'shortcode_action' );
```

Update: using [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to return the content of the output of `echo_ald_crp`.

Update 2: using [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) as highlighted by @jgraup in the comments.

Comment: It's probably better to use ob_get_clean() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php - ob_get_contents doesn't clear the output buffer.

Comment: @jgraup Great catch, I've updated the answer.

Comment: While you're at it, maybe wrap it all in the conditional. No need to run excess functions if nothing will yield ;)